# How to get permanent token?

Tags: apex, integration, connected-apps

I really need to get permanent token or dynamic generator. We set job in the server and this service will come to salesforce and get the data. To provide this, I created connected app, got the token from postman by myself and gave it. After a while (approximately 1 day), we faced with session id problem.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is the `refresh_token`.

> Access tokens have a limited lifetime specified by the session timeout in Salesforce. If an application uses an expired access token, a “Session expired or invalid” error is returned. If the application is using the web server or user-agent OAuth authentication flow, a refresh token is provided during authorization. Use this refresh token to get a new access token.

Take a look at [How Does the OAuth Refresh Token Fit Into the Authentication Flow?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm) documentation which details out as how you can get a refresh token and then utilize it going forward to get a new access token whenever it expires.

Follow [How Are Apps Authenticated with the Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm) to get details on how you can get the refresh token and then utilize it going forward.

Comment: When I try this method, i always get "expired access/refresh token" error. I couldn't understand that we put parameters "grant_type, refresh_token, client_id, client_secret" but what should i write to refresh token ???

Comment: You will need to first get the refresh token, and how to get that, you can take a look at [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm). I will also update it in my answer.

Comment: I have been trying but I couldn't get response. I really cannot du this. I tried it on my sandbox and made beginning of the authorization link test.salesforce..... but I couldn't get

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdemir Based on the format of SFSE, the answers are [specific to a question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In this scenario your question was more about which approach you can take and that was addressed in the answers as provided here. For your new issue, you will need to open a new question and provide all the details, the steps tried and issue you are facing for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Can we set the session timeout for a specific API client account to infinity, or a long time, say 30 years?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using an OAuth flow that is compatible with your situation, not just storing a Session Id.

Using OAuth will offer you the ability to re-authenticate to generate new tokens or obtain a refresh token you can exchange for a fresh token.

There's a lot of documentation available on this subject; see [Authenticate Apps with OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate.htm&type=5).

For a permanent server-to-server connection, you probably want to be implementing the [Web Server Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), which will provide you with a [refresh token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5) you can later use to get a new access token, or the [JWT Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5), which will allow you to continuously request access tokens.

Comment: Hi David, thx for answering. I have a problem related with refresh token. i followed the "Web Server Authentication Flow" and i guess there are problem about authentication. I allowed to access the request, salesforce throw an "URL No Longer Exists". How can i handle this problem?

Comment: @Halil you'll probably need to open a new question and include exactly what you did to get to that point.